# Make Numbered Equation in Groff

Tags: groff

Using the `ms` macros and `eqn`, is there some way to number an equation in Groff automatically similar to LaTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything built-in to the `ms` macros for this, but you can always use the base troff *number registers*.

Add to the start the file the definition and initialisation of your number register (starts at 0, increment by 1):

```troff
.nr myeqn 0 1
```

Then whereever you use it as

```
\n+[myeqn]
```

it will be incremented and replaced by the current value. Eg

```
.EQ
e sup {i pi} + 1 = 0
.EN
.sp -1
.tl ' ' '... \n+[myeqn]'
```

If you want to use the same number again it is `\n[myeqn]` instead.

Comment: What does `.tl` do? I can't find it in any man page.

Comment: It's in `man 7 groff`, and means *three part title*. `.tl 'a'b'c'` will put `a` on the left, `b` in the middle, and `c` on the right edge of the line.

Answer (score 1):

meuh's answer is correct but not *quite* idiomatic.

There is a simpler way to get the equation number set to the right of the equation than messing with `sp` and `tl` requests.

*ms*'s `EQ` macro accepts (optional) arguments, and if you give it a second argument, *ms* will set it to the right of the equation display for you.

```
    .EQ [align [label]]
    .EN Demarcate an equation to be processed by the eqn preprocessor.
        The equation is centered by default; align can be C, L, or I to
        (explicitly) center, left‐align, or indent it by \n[DI],
        respectively.  If specified, label is set right‐aligned.
```

The foregoing is from the *groff_ms*(7) page in groff Git.  The version of the page in *groff* 1.22.4 is not as comprehensive.

So you can rewrite meuh's solution more briefly.

```
.nr myeqn 0 1
.\" ...stuff...
.EQ C \n+[myeqn]
e sup {i pi} + 1 = 0
.EN
```